# " VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode" when deploying contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, contract-deployment, openzeppelin

I am getting the following error when deploying with web3js a smart contract based on [Open Zeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol):

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
    at Object.InvalidResponse (errors.js:35)
    at requestmanager.js:86
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (httpprovider.js:122)
```

where the contract code is

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

import "./libs/zeppelin/crowdsale/CappedCrowdsale.sol";
import "./libs/zeppelin/crowdsale/FinalizableCrowdsale.sol";
import './TestToken.sol';

contract SampleCrowdsale is CappedCrowdsale, FinalizableCrowdsale {

    TestToken public testToken ;

  function SampleCrowdsale(uint256 _startTime, uint256 _endTime, uint256 _rate, uint256 _goal, uint256 _cap, address _wallet, address _tokenContractAddress)
    CappedCrowdsale(_cap)
    FinalizableCrowdsale()
    Crowdsale(_startTime, _endTime, _rate, _wallet)
  {

    testToken = TestToken(_tokenContractAddress);
  }

  function createTokenContract() internal returns (MintableToken) {
    return testToken;
  }

}
```

However everything works when I change `FinalizableCrowdsale` to `RefundableCrowdsale`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

import "./libs/zeppelin/crowdsale/CappedCrowdsale.sol";
import "./libs/zeppelin/crowdsale/RefundableCrowdsale.sol";
import './TestToken.sol';

contract SampleCrowdsale is CappedCrowdsale, RefundableCrowdsale {

    TestToken public testToken ;

  function SampleCrowdsale(uint256 _startTime, uint256 _endTime, uint256 _rate, uint256 _goal, uint256 _cap, address _wallet, address _tokenContractAddress)
    CappedCrowdsale(_cap)
    FinalizableCrowdsale()
    Crowdsale(_startTime, _endTime, _rate, _wallet)
  {
    require(_goal <= _cap);
    testToken = TestToken(_tokenContractAddress);
  }

  function createTokenContract() internal returns (MintableToken) {
    return testToken;
  }

}
```

**Question:** Can anyone please explain to me why the first contract that uses `FinalizableCrowdsale` is throwing that error? `RefundableCrowdsale` inherits `FinalizableCrowdsale` but isnt giving any errors...

Related Files:

1. https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol
2. https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/crowdsale/FinalizableCrowdsale.sol
3. https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/crowdsale/RefundableCrowdsale.sol

Answer (score 1):

I was able to deploy your `FinalizableCrowdsale` `SampleCrowdsale` after I removed the `FinalizableCrowdsale()` call from the constructor.

I used the following parameters in the constructor call:

```
1511030956, 1511117356, 1, 100, 200, "0x01", "0x02"
```

I deployed my contract using Remix, so I modified the code slightly to this (especially since I didn't have the TestToken code):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/CappedCrowdsale.sol";
import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/FinalizableCrowdsale.sol";
import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/RefundableCrowdsale.sol";
import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/MintableToken.sol";

contract SampleCrowdsale is CappedCrowdsale, FinalizableCrowdsale {

    MintableToken public testToken ;

  function SampleCrowdsale(uint256 _startTime, uint256 _endTime, uint256 _rate, uint256 _goal, uint256 _cap, address _wallet, address _tokenContractAddress)
    CappedCrowdsale(_cap)
    Crowdsale(_startTime, _endTime, _rate, _wallet)
  {

    testToken = MintableToken(_tokenContractAddress);
  }

  function createTokenContract() internal returns (MintableToken) {
    return testToken;
  }

}
```

One thing that I noticed is that `RefundableCrowdsale` requires one argument for its constructor, where as `FinalizableCrowdsale` does not and [it isn't necessary to call a parent's constructor if it doesn't take any arguments](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/18008/8469).

I suspect that this minor detail is the cause of the problem.

Comment: When I changed `_startTime` from `1510889758` to `1520889758`, it started working! Why is the start time important?

Comment: Where can I find this Crowdsale contract? not able to locate "FinalizableCrowdsale.sol" file